# How to print specific field that matches with a regex in awk

Tags: printing, awk, field

It is a simple question but I didn't find an answer...
I have a tab separated files with many rows and different number of fields in each row. Like this:

```
a1_j a2_f a3_f a10_g a8_t a2_e
a2_j
a6_h a8_o 
a9_g
```

I just want to print those fields that start with a2, but not the whole line, just the matched fields.Like this:

```
a2_f
a2_e
a2_j
```

I tried with awk, with no success.

Comment: you can do it with awk. Part of the Stackoverflow philosophy is to help people get your code working. Edit your question to show what you have tried, and people will be more than happy to show multiple ways to get what you need AND help you understand what was missing in your code. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I would use grep to do this:

```
grep -o 'a2_[a-z]' file
```

The `-o` switch means that only matches are printed, each on a separate line.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through all the fields with a for loop, or use `fmt` to put all the fields on 1 line:

```
~$ fmt -w1 f
a1_j
a2_f
a3_f
a10_g
a8_t
a2_e
a2_j
a6_h
a8_o
a9_g
```

and then grep with `grep` or if you want to use `awk`:

```
~$ fmt -w1 f | awk '/a2/{print}'
a2_f
a2_e
a2_j
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and `\s`:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s' '/^a2/' file
a2_f
a2_e
a2_j
```

Comment: I was waiting for that!